# installing python-scitools and matplotlib dependencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install python-scitools via 'sudo apt-get install python-scitools'.
It gives the following output

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
python-matplotlib
Suggested packages:
python-excelerator python-matplotlib-doc python-traits python-wxgtk2.8octave
The following NEW packages will be installed:
python-matplotlib python-scitools
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 203 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,596 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,250 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

The point is that I already installed python-matplotlib manually (because I needed latest version 1.2.0).

If I tipe 'matplotlib.**path**' in ipython, it returns

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib']
```

My question is, How can I tell the system, matplotlib is installed?

As you guessed, I am amateur with this things.

thank you

Comment: You can use `checkinstall` to install matplotlib so that Ubuntu would recognize it - instead `python setup.py install` as last step in your install process use `sudo checkinstall python setup.py install`.

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Comment: Unfortunately I was running out of time so I stopped trying to install it. However, now it is possible to install matplotlib 1.2 via "apt-get", so I don't need it any more. Should I set it "solved"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing stuff by hand vs installing via package manager do not play nice together.  You can always build what ever you want *on top of* the packages, but you can not (easily) go the other way.

The dependency check that `apt` is doing are against it's internal database, and it *rightly* thinks that `matplotlib` is not installed.  This is a feature, not a bug, as it allows the packaging system to very quickly determine if the dependencies are installed.  You can probably build your own `.deb` to install, but that can be a bit of a hassle (as it involves understanding the debian build system).

You might be able to install the packaged version and just make sure your hand installed version is higher is `PYTHONPATH` than the system one.  It wastes a bit of hdd space, but meh.
(you can set the location of the install path via `setupy.py install --prefix=/path/to/where/ever`).

`PYTHONPATH` is an enviromental variable so you can set it using a whole slew of methods.

```
PYTHONPATH=/your/path:$PYTHONPATH ipython
```

will set the variable for just one process.  You can also add

```
PYTHONPATH=/your/path:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`, I always get the role of those two mixed up) which will get run every time you start  a shell.

If that does not work, you probably need to use the packaged version of `matplotlib` (which may require deleting your current installation of it), or installing everything you want, which depends on `matplotlib`, by hand.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, I've never had any problems using numpy from the repos and the stable branch of matplotlib from github.  Maybe I've just been lucky?

Comment: @AdamCadien I should have been more clear, installing stuff by hand the depends on stuff installed from the repo is fine, installing stuff from the repo that depends on stuff you installed by hand that is the problem.

Comment: Yes very good point, the repos will link directly against their internal code base.  In fact I don't know that its possible to instruct them to link against a local code base, probably a good question for superuser.

Comment: I tried installing _matplotlib_ from repositories, and when I start ipython it launches version 1.1.1, not the manually installed, so I type

>>>>`import sys`

>>>>`sys.path`
Out[2]:

['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QuickTile-0.1.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 ....
 ]

So I do `sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib')` hopping it works. However, if I close and open ipython I see my insertion in `sys.path` is not saved. How can I save it correctly?

Comment: @manolius see edit.  If it still does not make sense, you should ask a new question specifically about setting the environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib
```

To remove the matplotlib install by apt-get?  Once you've done that you'll need to make sure your system can find the matplotlib you installed by hand, but I suspect you've already done that during the install process.

Comment: yes, I tried this, but >'apt-get remove python-matplotlib' also removes the scitools, so I am at the beginning again